# Discord JS v14 - Get all the servers where the member is in

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using the following code to retrieve all the server's IDs where the member is in. I'm am getting the member from the `interaction`. Can someone help me?

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  const guilds = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch();
  const userGuilds = guilds.filter(
    guild => guild.members.cache.has(interaction.user.id)
  );
  const guildIDs = userGuilds.map(guild => guild.id);
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`guilds.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a collection of `OAuth2Guild`s, and not `Guild` objects. `OAuth2Guild` is a partial guild received when using `GuildManager#fetch` to fetch multiple guilds and it doesn't have a `members` property.

You can [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/OAuth2Guild?scrollTo=fetch) the guild though. But not in a `filter()` as it won't work with Promises. So first, you'll need to fetch all these partial guilds and wait for them to be resolved than filter those. Something like this should work as expected:

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  const partialGuilds = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch();
  const guilds = await Promise.all(
    partialGuilds.map((partialGuild) => partialGuild.fetch()),
  );

  const userGuilds = guilds.filter((guild) =>
    guild.members.cache.has(interaction.user.id),
  );
  const guildIDs = userGuilds.map((guild) => guild.id);
}
```

But do you need to fetch all the guilds? `client.guilds` should include all of the guilds the client is currently handling, mapped by their IDs. As long as sharding isn't being used, this will be every guild the bot is a member of.

So I think this would be easier:

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  const userGuilds = interaction.client.guilds.cache.filter((guild) =>
    guild.members.cache.has(interaction.user.id),
  );
  const guildIDs = userGuilds.map((guild) => guild.id);
}
```

Comment: That's not what I need. I wanna get every server that the user (not the bot) is part of. Do you understand my problem?

Comment: I fixed the original issue you had. No, I don't understand. Do you want to get a full list of servers a discord user is in even if your bot is not in those servers?